# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español para decir "con forma de teta"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Pregunta rápida:

Tengo una amiga gallega que de vez en cuando nos obsequia con quesos de tetilla de su tierra. Y me pregunto yo: ¿existe alguna palabra para decir "con forma de teta", al igual que "ovoidal" u "ovoide" significan "con forma de huevo de gallina"? Si no, ¿se podría construir un neologismo usando algún afijo que signifique "con forma de"?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mira, una que acabo de encontrar:

> **[mamiforme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6NmKbG)**
>
> 1. adj. De forma de mama (‖ órgano glanduloso).

Que usa el sufijo

> **[-forme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IFMwPcG)**
>
> Del lat. *-formis*, de la raíz de *forma*.
>
> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'en forma de'.

Comment: *Mamiforme* me parece bien, porque en inglés uso *mammiform*.

Comment: ja! yo iba a sugerir esta palabra de pura broma, eso o "pectiforme"

Answer (score 6):

Sufijo:
[**-oide**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qx2UAfv):

> Del lat. *-oīdes*, y este del gr. *-οειδής -oeidḗs* u *-οειδές -oeidés*, de *-ο- -o-*, vocal de unión, y *-ειδής -eidḗs* o *-ειδές -eidés* 'semejante a', de la raíz de *εἶδος eîdos* 'forma'.
>   1. elem. compos. Significa 'parecido a', 'en forma de'. *Metaloide. Androide.* Adopta también las formas -oideo, -oides. *Lipoideo, hialoideo. Cuboides, deltoides*.

Palabra:
[**mastoides**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OZLRAwU)

> Del lat. cient. *mastoides*, y este del gr. *μαστοειδής mastoeidḗs*, de *μαστός mastós* 'mama' y *-ειδής -eidḗs* 'semejante a'.
>
> 1. adj. Zool. **De forma de mama.** Se dice de la apófisis del hueso temporal de los mamíferos, situada detrás y debajo de la oreja. U. t. c. s. m.

Pero se utiliza exclusivamente (que yo sepa) para la apófisis del hueso temporal, por lo que usarla para otra cosa solo generaría confusión.

Una alternativa a considerar sería
[**mamilar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6U58CL)

> 1. adj. En forma de mamila.

siendo [**mamila**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6OdVEY):

> 1. f. Anat. Parte principal de la teta o pecho de la hembra, exceptuando el pezón.

Comment: Si este es el sufijo a usar, ¿la respuesta a la pregunta sería "tetoide"?

Comment: también podría ser "tetiforme": http://dle.rae.es/?id=IFMwPcG